# Informatica: Source fields are not visible

Tags: etl, informatica

Mapping was created by another user and fields in Source tables are visible for him. When I open the same Mapping in my Informatica, Source fields are not visible, look empty, but if I click on table I see fields (Port names) in grey. Can't drag and drop them to Application Source Qualifier.

User who sees fields in his Informatica on his computer, logged in on mine and also doesn't see fields of Source tables.

Where in Informatica settings I can change something to make source fields visible?

Comment: The mapping might be checked out to the other user. He has to check in the mapping for you to see the updated mapping. Also, you will need to check out the mapping to do any modification.

Comment: mapping was checked in

Answer (score 0):

Informatica support team advised to send them logs of Windows activities https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/1/154250.aspx. This didn't help.

What helped is re-installation of Windows, I installed Windows 10, Informatica works properly now, I can see sources.